# python regex- getting everything (except \n) between two characters in a multiline string

Tags: python, regex

I have file like this as input:

```
>X0
CUUGACGAUCA
CGCAUCG
>X55
UACGGCGG
UUCAGC
AUCG
>X300
AAACCCGGGG
```

and I need to get the concatenation of lines between '>' characters:

```
CUUGACGAUCACGCAUCG
UACGGCGGUUCAGCAUCG
AAACCCGGGG
```

My attempt was to use `"re.match(r'^>.*\n(.*)>.*' ,a,re.DOTALL)"` and then delete '\n' from each match, but the regex is not returning anything. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.  - Jamie Zawinski

That being said, why not do this much more understandable string processing?

```
tmp = []
seqs = []
with open('txtfile') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            seqs.append(''.join(tmp))
            tmp = []
        else:
            tmp.append(line.strip())
    else:
        seqs.pop(0)
        seqs.append(''.join(tmp))
```

Alternatively, if you really want to use a regex, you could try first stripping the newlines and then splitting by the `>X[digit]` patterns:

```
re.split(r'>X\d+', re.sub(r'\n', '', data))
```

But that has the downside that the entire textfile has to be loaded into the variable `data`, which is not as interesting for large file (which in bio-informatics are quite common). So even then, the approach given first is more interesting, memory-wise, as you could process each finished DNA/RNA-sequence in turn.

Answer (score 1):

I would have simply done:

```
s = file.read()    #or whatever string yu have
sar = "".join(s.split())   #this will remove newlines
sar = sar.split('>')   #processing your splitter 
for tstr in sar:
    print tstr #this is the concatenation of lines between '>' characters:
```

Answer (score 0):

A *regex* will work well for this application, but to do this with a *regex*, you need to use a *lookahead assertion*. This essentially means that the *regex* looks for, but does not consume, what's defined within the lookahead `(?=...)`, where `...` is for what you're looking ahead.

So, incorporating this into a full pattern, you would get this:

```
>(.+?)(?=>|$)
```

Distilling this, this pattern looks for a `>` as the starting point, and then captures everything up to the point where it sees either another `>` or the end of the string, but -- and this is key -- it doesn't consume the ending `>`, so it's available to start the next instance.

You'll also need to use the `DOTALL` flag to ensure newlines match the `.` and the `findall` function to return all matches.

So, something like this will work:

```
#!/usr/env/python

import re

string = """>X0
CUUGACGAUCA
CGCAUCG
>X55
UACGGCGG
UUCAGC
AUCG
>X300
AAACCCGGGG"""

res = re.findall('>(.+?)(?=>|$)', string, re.DOTALL)

print "results: {0}".format(res)
```

The output is:

```
results: ['X0\nCUUGACGAUCA\nCGCAUCG\n', 'X55\nUACGGCGG\nUUCAGC\nAUCG\n', 'X300\nAAACCCGGGG']
```

See the [Python regex doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for more regex details.

If you don't want the newlines in the result, you can then use `string.replace` to remove those from each item in the list.